# Set expression for @Pointcut

Tags: spring

I want to set annotation for class and when I call anyone method of object this class to execute interceptor before execute method.

```
@MyAnn
public class SomeClass {

    public void someMethod1() {}
    public void someMethod2() {}
}

@Aspect
public class SomeInterceptor {

    @Pointcut("execution(@my.package.aop.MyAnn* *.*(..))")
    public void checkMethod() {}

    @Around("checkMethod()")
    public Object method(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

    }
}
```

What expression should be set in @Pointcut(...) that all methods my class processed the interceptor before execution?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution

```
@Pointcut("execution(public * *(..))")
private void anyPublicOperation() {}

@Pointcut("within(@my.package.aop.MyAnn *)")
private void withinMyAnn() {}

@Pointcut("anyPublicOperation() && withinMyAnn()")
public void checkMethod() {}
```

If there is a more successful solution I will be happy to see in the comments